# setInterval for sum random quantity

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I'm trying to create a simple JS code that allow me to sum a random quantity to an amount. Whenever this amount reach 60000, it will stop.

This is my code:

```
let tickets = 35000;


setInterval(function(){
  console.log(tickets);
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(350-100+1)+100);
  let sum = tickets + random;
  let totalSum = sum + random;

  console.log('Total sum =' + totalSum);

  if (tickets >= 60000) {
    console.log("Sold out");
    clearInterval();
  }
}, 1000);
```

I am trying to figure out how to sum properlu, cause everytime sum 35000 + random number but doesnt increase, just replace the previous random number. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the *intervalID* from [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and use this to stop the interval with [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

As well cou need to update `tickets` as well. It is unclear why you take a local variable for `sum` and `totalSum`.

```js
let tickets = 35000,
    intervalID = setInterval(function() { // assign intervalID
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (350 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        tickets += random;
        console.log(tickets);

        if (tickets >= 60000) {
            console.log("Sold out");
            clearInterval(intervalID); // use intervalID here
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: `tickets` is not updated. So, `tickets >= 60000` will always be false

Comment: thank you! yes that's true, didn't realize I had to update "ticket", really appreciate your help guys!

Comment: @NinaScholz could you help me to figure out this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881219/setinterval-restart-when-page-is-refreshed ?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to set the `tickets` variable again and again. And also put `60000` value check before updating tickets value. Also store `setInterval` id in a variable, which you will later use in `clearInterval`.

```js
let tickets = 35000;


let interval = setInterval(function(){
  console.log(tickets);
  if (tickets >= 60000) {
    console.log("Sold out");
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(350-100+1)+100);
  tickets += random;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't want tickets to increase once we're sold out, so put that in an `else` statement.

```js
var tickets = 35000;

var sell = setInterval(function() {
  console.log(tickets);
  if (tickets >= 60000) {
    console.log("Sold out");
    clearInterval(sell);
  }
  else {
    tickets += rando(100, 350);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

If you want to pick back up where you left off on refresh, store the `tickets` value in [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) (and grab it from there when needed) like this:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
  var tickets;
  var sell = setInterval(function() {
    tickets = Number(window.localStorage.getItem("tickets") || 35000);
    console.log(tickets);
    if (tickets >= 60000) {
      console.log("Sold out");
      clearInterval(sell);
    }
    else {
      window.localStorage.setItem("tickets", tickets + rando(100, 350));
    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

All this code uses [rando.js](https://randojs.com) to simplify the randomness and make it more readable. Feel free to check out the website if you want, but really, if you want to use this code just make sure the following is in the head tag of your html document and you'll be good to go:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks Aaron! very appreciate. Do you know how can I do to dont restart the counter when page is refreshed? I mean, everytime I refresh the counter starts from 35000. I need no matter you refresh or you are new in the site, the counter will show you the new quantity.

Comment: You mean you want to pick back up where you left off when revisiting the page? Sure, check my updated code.

Comment: thank you for your kind support. It really works! thank you so much, really helpfull

Comment: Happy to help! If you're satisfied with this solution, please mark it with an upvote and an accepted checkmark to let others know it's good. It also gives me some points. Thanks! *EDIT:* Never mind, I see you've already accepted another answer. If you're more satisfied with that one then there's no need to change. Cheers!